# Model Initialization - Passing parameters - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am having trouble initializing my model.

I am trying to build a model which takes a url_address string on initialization, utilizes DocRaptor to build a PDF, then uses pdf-reader to read data from that PDF, and finally remove the stored PDF.

When I have a blank model, I can save using Rails 5 forms, as per the introductory Rails 5 guide, here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I built a new project from scratch using a postgresql database, and set about with the Guide. I was able to save models just fine with a blank UrlDataModel definition. However, when I edited my model to contain functionality necessary to retrieve the PDF and read it, I get a

```
NoMethodError - undefined method '[]' for nil:Class
```

I do know this error means that my model is empty, so I'm trying to troubleshoot how that happens.

The controller fails on

```
@url_data_model.save
```

My repo is here: https://github.com/blueMesaEngineering/Minotaur-hoof

Model follows here:

---

```
class UrlDataModel < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :url_address, :pdf_version, :producer, :title, :metadata, :page_count

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @url_address = attributes[:url_address]
    @pdf_version = attributes[:pdf_version]
    @producer = attributes[:producer]
    @title = attributes[:title]
    @metadata = attributes[:metadata]
    @page_count = attributes[:page_count]
  end

  def after_initialize
    buildModelFromURLViaPDF
  end

  def buildModelFromURLViaPDF
    convertURLToPDF
    readPDFData
    deletePDF
  end

  def convertURLToPDF
    require 'bundler/setup'
    Bundler.require

    DocRaptor.configure do |dr|
      dr.username = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE' # this key works for test documents
      # dr.debugging = true
    end

    $docraptor = DocRaptor::DocApi.new

    begin
      logPathName = './storage/Logs/standardOutput/output.txt'
      errorLogPathName = './storage/Logs/Error/'
      pathName = './storage/PDFs/'
      # url         = "http://docraptor.com/examples/invoice.html"
      url = 'http://www.docraptor.com'
      @url_address = url

      fileNamePDF  = 'docraptor-ruby.pdf'

      create_response = $docraptor.create_async_doc(
        test: true, # test documents are free but watermarked
        document_url: url, # or use a url
        name: fileNamePDF, # help you find a document later
        document_type: 'pdf' # pdf or xls or xlsx
      )

      loop do
        status_response = $docraptor.get_async_doc_status(create_response.status_id)

        # puts "doc status: #{status_response.status}"

        case status_response.status

        when 'completed'
          doc_response = $docraptor.get_async_doc(status_response.download_id)
          File.open('./storage/PDFs/docraptor-ruby.pdf', 'wb') do |file|
            file.write(doc_response)
          end
          # puts "Wrote PDF to " + pathName + fileNamePDF

          break

        when 'failed'

          # puts "FAILED"
          # puts status_response
          break

        else

          sleep 1

      end
      end
    rescue DocRaptor::ApiError => error
      # puts "#{error.class}: #{error.message}"
      # puts error.code          # HTTP response code
      # puts error.response_body # HTTP response body
      # puts error.backtrace[0..3].join("\n")
    end
  end

  def readPDFData
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'pdf/reader'

    fileName = './storage/PDFs/docraptor-ruby.pdf'

    PDF::Reader.open(fileName) do |reader|
      @pdf_version = reader.pdf_version
      # @producer   = reader.producer
      # @title     = reader.title
      @metadata = reader.metadata
      @page_count = reader.page_count
    end
  end

  def deletePDF
    require 'fileutils'

    FileUtils.rm_rf('./storage/PDFs/docraptor-ruby.pdf')
  end
end
```

Penny for your thoughts? I'm on here for the rest of the evening, so I will be able to respond directly. Thank you for taking a look!

Cheers.

Controller: https://pastebin.com/QVaHCMep

Stack Trace: https://pastebin.com/uQbXgiaH

Comment: A couple (or four) things. First, you should probably put the whole stack trace in your question (it's often easier to get a sense of the error and where it might be coming from). Second, IMO you are significantly overloading the responsibility of that model. Third, it seems strange to have those `require` statements sprinkled throughout (and configure statements, too). Fourth, and finally, it looks like a global variable in there (`$docraptor`) which might not be a big deal but I personally never use.

Comment: Where is the code where you are actually initializing the model and saving it? Post it here please. And you should probably remove the comments in your code here, doesn't really help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Hello - Thanks for the response. I am self-taught with respect to Ruby and Rails, so I am always learning. Some of the apparent globals ($docraptor) were in some of the documentation, but I will take it under advisement.  Some things seemed to break when I left requires in the higher level of the class, but I will double check. Should some of this be in the controller?  I was building this under the guidelines of a "thin controller" model. I'm not sure if that's best though. Comments have been removed accordingly.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Heroku app: https://murmuring-chamber-54696.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I would advise opening rails console and trying to save a record with the same attributes you'd get from the controller. If there's an error look at the stack trace to determine what line it originated from. I'm afraid without this info this question is impossible to answer. I'm assuming that since you can call `@url_data_model.save` you have already initialized the record without error. None of the other model code actually gets run with the code you've shown

Comment: Hi max - Thanks for the help. It makes sense now that you mention that the other code doesn't get run. I'm getting back to this project now. I'll check out the console and see if I can save a record. Thanks!